# Journal article reference for Illumina's "near monopoly"

Tags: illumina, sra

*Apologies if the question is out of the scope of the bioinformatics SE. Please feel free to close it if it is the case.*

Recently, I have been going into a rabbit hole of papers that discuss the progress of sequencing technologies, from the earliest attempts to Sanger, massively parallel sequencing, and long-read sequencing.

To my surprise, I was not able to find any recent reference that direclty highlights Illumina's market dominance. The closest I could find was the [2010 SRA paper](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/39/suppl_1/D19/2505848) ("Almost 80% [...]") that briefly describes the proportion of records per platform or [this paper](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb4168) that alludes to Illumina's monopoly. How come it seems so difficult to find recent reports on the use of each sequencing platform?

Am I missing something there, or am I just looking for something that is not that interesting? To be fair, it's probably easier to query the SRA directly to get my answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Personally (just my opinion) this is much more suited for Biology SE, however someone here may know the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is neither really a bioinformatic question, not suited for biology SE. I recommend a google search for "Illumina sequencing market share" which for me yielded some interesting articles, mainly from business-related websites and newspapers. Generally they say that in the (short-read) sequencing field Illumina has a 70-80% share right now which is roughly what I would have intuitively anticipated.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid this isn't on topic here as it isn't about bioinformatics as a science but about the market dominance of a specific company. For what it's worth, this isn't the kind of thing you would expect to find a scientific paper on, if you want a source to cite, look at newspapers, or market analyses. There is no biological point to be made with respect to which company dominates a given market.